# email attachment not received magento form

Tags: forms, magento, magento-1.9, email-attachments, contact-form

create custom form with email file jpg attached successfully sent to server. but the problem is, there's no email attached when receive email. try looking for all this forum no result. still get no email attached on receiving email. here's my code on indexcontroller.

upload server controlling

```
$fileName = '';
        if (isset($_FILES['attachment']['name']) && $_FILES['attachment']['name'] != '') {
            try {           
                    $fileName       = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
                    $fileExt        = strtolower(substr(strrchr($fileName, ".") ,1));
                    $fileNamewoe    = rtrim($fileName, $fileExt);
                    $fileName       = preg_replace('/\s+', '', $fileNamewoe) . time() . '.' . $fileExt;
                $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('attachment');
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('doc', 'docx','pdf', 'jpg'));
                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'confirm' . DS ;
                if(!is_dir($path)){
                    mkdir($path, 0777, true);
                }
                $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['attachment']['confirm'] );             
                $newFilename = $uploader->getUploadedFileName();


            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $error = true;
            }
        }
```

code to call email file attached

```
              $attachmentFilePath = Mage::getBaseDir('media'). DS . 'confirm' . DS . $fileName;
              if(file_exists($attachmentFilePath)){
                $fileContents = file_get_contents($attachmentFilePath);
                $attachment   = $mail->getMail()->createAttachment($fileContents);
                $attachment->filename = $fileName;
            }
```

hope someone can help my problem thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
    //upload code
   $fileName = '';
        if (isset($_FILES['attachment']['name']) && $_FILES['attachment']['name'] != '') {
            try {           
                    $fileName       = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
                    $fileExt        = strtolower(substr(strrchr($fileName, ".") ,1));
                    $fileNamewoe    = rtrim($fileName, $fileExt);
                    $fileName       = preg_replace('/\s+', '', $fileNamewoe) . time() . '.' . $fileExt;
                $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('attachment');
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('doc', 'docx','pdf', 'jpg'));
                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'confirm' . DS ;
                if(!is_dir($path)){
                    mkdir($path, 0777, true);
                }
                $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['attachment']['confirm'] );             
                $newFilename = $uploader->getUploadedFileName();
  $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
      $mailTemplate->setSenderName('Sender Name'); 
      $mailTemplate->setSenderEmail('sender@sender.email');
      $mailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('Subject Title');
      $mailTemplate->setTemplateText('Body Text');
      // add attachment
      $mailTemplate->getMail()->createAttachment(
              file_get_contents($path.$newFilename), //location of file
              Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
              Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
              Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
                basename( $newFilename )
      );
      $mailTemplate->send('toemail@email.com','subject','set message');

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $error = true;
            }
        }
```